# Symfony POST variable always empty

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

Here is my Symfony controller:

```
class MyPageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $postData = $request->request->get('manage');
        return new Response('<html><body>Post: '.$postData.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="/..." method="POST" id="entity">
    <input type="text" value="This is the value" id="manage" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`$postData` is always empty.

I've tryed also:

```
$postData = $request->request->get('entity');
```

`$postData['manage']` is empty too!

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 8):

i guess it's not a symfony issue, just html, your input needs `name` attribute so it can be included in POST

```
<form action="/..." method="POST" id="entity">
<input type="text" value="This is the value" name="manage" />
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! I've made a stupid mistake - entered the "id" instead on "name" attribute...