# Symfony2 $request->request is empty

Tags: php, symfony

I have a page with two forms that can be submitted separately. I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022166/symfony-post-variable-always-empty) to check which form was submitted, but $request->request is always an empty array. What am I missing?

```
public function submitAction(Request $request) {
        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $processes = $dm->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:Process')->findAll();

        $formClients = $this->createForm(new FiltersFormType(), $processes);
        $formClients->handleRequest($request);

        $formSuppliers = $this->createForm(new SupplierFormType(), $processes);
        $formSuppliers->handleRequest($request);
}
```

Edit: it's being posted via GET

Comment: Can you paste also your form pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it, to check if a key is present, when posting via GET:

`$request->query->get($formClients->getName())`

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like:

```
public function submitAction() {

    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    (...)

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing enough information before, but the form is submitted via GET. I'm now using ``$request->query->has($formClients->getName())`` to check if my key exists, but it still doesn't work. This query contains a ``['parameters':protected]`` which then contains the form name.. I don't understand how to reach it, because this parameters is not accessible.